# Why do I need to set static pointer to nil before reassigning in this case

Tags: objective-c, static, zombie-process

I have a *"always keep a static reference on the last created object" pattern* for one of my classes.
When I create a new instance of it, the static pointer should been set to this new instance.
Solved the way below:

```
static AViewController *actualSelf = nil;

+ (AViewController *) getActualSelf {
    return actualSelf;
}

- (AViewController *) init {
    self = [super init];
    self.title = @"Title";

    actualSelf = nil; // Why do I need this line the second time init gets called?

    actualSelf = self; // this is the only line which sets actualSelf

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    actualSelf = nil;
}

…SOME IMPORTANT MUST BE MISSING, BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT
```

- create AViewController a > Init gets called > Static pointer is set to a
- create AViewController b > Init gets called > Static pointer should be set to b. But the static pointer is not set to b! It's sets itself from *a* to nil!

Object a is most of the time deallocated before b gets created.

Do I always need to reset the static variables to nil when deallocating them? NO, see my own answer below.

**Without the line "actualSelf = nil;", through ARC object a gets deallocated in the moment actualSelf is set to object b.**

Comment: Why do you think you need that line?

Comment: Because without, it does not work

Comment: `init` methods should only be called once for the same object, so if you call it for a second time, you should probably re-visit your architecture.

Comment: Zaph is correct, you don't need that line.  Your problem lies elsewhere.  Perhaps you're not setting actualSelf to nil after you dealloc it and other objects are getting a stale reference to memory you've deleted.  Try setting the 'enable zombies' option.  Also, you really shouldn't turn a view controller into a singleton.  Make your, vc, use it, throw it away when you're done with it.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, why do I need to set it to nil in dealloc?

Comment: @Monolo You don't understood it, they are 2 different objects, not existing at the same time

Comment: @Viktor, because somewhere else in your code you must be checking if that var is nil or not to determine if you should make a new one or use the existing one.  That code would normally be in your getActualSelf method, but I see it's not there.  If you don't nil the value after you dealloc (in this case only, not as a general rule) then you may try to use a pointer that is referencing already released memory.

Comment: @Dave Then why do I need to set it to nil, when I know init get's called before. Why is actualSelf = self not enough? Shouldn't it set actualSelf to a new object, regardless what it is before?

Comment: If actualSelf was also a property and something was doing a self.actualSelf aka [setActualSelf:self] then you'd be referencing the bogus memory by setting to the new memory; but think you'd need to add "self." to get that behavior so I don't know.  I am 100% certain that everyone's giving you good advice here.  That line is not needed, it is not your problem.  The bug lies elsewhere.  IMO, you should delete all this code and attack the problem another way.  Keep your VC light and move the memory into your model (and purge it out when the view isn't in front of the user), etc.

Comment: @Dave: "Keep your VC light and move the memory into your model" Exactly, data should be in a Data Model, not a view controller. A VC is the middle-man between the data and a view.

Comment: @Zaph it works in the first object, it is automatically set to nil. So no need for that. Without calling init it is already nil.

Comment: If you don't know why something works don't do it. Writing code is not a guessing game, lines of code are (should be) written only when knows exactly what it does and why. Allan Kelly: "Two Wrongs Can Make a Right (and Are Difficult to Fix)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - create AViewController a > Init gets called > Static pointer is set to a
> - create AViewController b > Init gets called > Static pointer should be set to b. But the static pointer is not set to b! It's sets itself
>     from *a* to nil!

Probably nothing other than `actualSelf` has ownership of `a`. Therefore, `actualSelf = self;` during the initialization of `b` causes `a` to be fully released and thus deallocated. During the `-dealloc` of `a`, it sets `actualSelf` to `nil`. Apparently, this is coming after the assignment of `actualSelf` to the new `self` (object `b`).  (The precise order of operations of the ARC-supplied `-release` call vis-a-vis the assignment of `actualSelf` is unpredictable.)

The very fact that you are assigning `actualSelf` to `nil` in the `-dealloc` method smells bad. It suggests that `actualSelf` should be `__weak` because if it's holding a strong reference to an object, then that object can't be deallocated.

At the very least, `-dealloc` should test if `actualSelf` equals `self` before resetting it. But that will never be true so long as `actualSelf` is a strong reference, since a strongly referenced object can't be deallocated.

This whole approach is deeply problematic. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Wow, great answer. Good you understood my question, even after I got down voted.

Comment: I used it in UI programming to get access to a customized log screen, showing information about the downloaded resources. The user decides when and what to download. Then the log screen gets customized by the downloaded resource. Thought it would be easy to get a pointer from everywhere.

Comment: __weak is only supported at iOS 5.0 or higher, but that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Then use `__unsafe_unretained`.

Answer (score 2):

```
actualSelf = nil; // WHY DO I NEED THIS LINE?
```

You don't need the line, it accomplishes nothing and will probably be eliminated by the compiler optimizer in a release build.

The class is not a singleton.

The rest of the answer has been deleted because the question has been modified.

Comment: Ok to make it clear actualSelf is a static variable, thought it was clear when writing about singletons. But it is my code after all. sorry.

Comment: When I have not set it to nil, never. The actualSelf will not point on the new object, even when setting it the second time init is called.

Comment: I need that line, you only say it should be in the dealloc method. But  you never explained and the explanation would be an answer

Comment: @Viktor, sorry I typed an answer to that question in the comments a while ago.  I think I didn't hit the 'add comment' button?  Sorry about that.  After you dealloc that object, your actualSelf variable is still pointing to the memory location that used to hold the object.  It is now a "dangling pointer" and is dangerous.  If you use it again, it might appear to work because the memory where the object used to be still holds parts of the object - OR it will crash hard.  So - after you dealloc (in this example only; not as a general rule) you must set your actualSelf to nil.

Comment: global static vars will be initialized to 0/null/nil, local statics are not initialized.  It is common practice to always explicitly init static vars yourself, @Zaph recommended you do that in his answer.

Comment: @Zeph it is needed in ARC with a code like that (because it is a strong pointer), because it got automatically deallocated through ARC the moment it got assigned, and the static pointer was the only one left to object a.